# Error handling with Try match inside an udf - and log row where it failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, error-handling, user-defined-functions

Scala version 2.11 and Spark 2.0.1.

I have a dataframe where I am doing some operations inside an udf. I want to be able to have the operations run and return error only on rows where it failed. I also would like to return success/failure as an additional field. Pass/Fail can be on a separate column.

This is what I tried:

```
val df = Seq(("as", 1, "df"), ("1", 2, "3")).toDF("a", "b", "c")
val df1 = Seq(("1", 1, "3"), ("1", 2, "3")).toDF("a", "b", "c")

def myUdf = udf((i: String, j: Int, k: Int) => { 
   def test (ii:String, jj:Int, kk:Int): Try[Int] = {
     val q = i.toInt * j * k.toInt
     val m = q * i.toInt
     return (Try(q))
  }
  val q = Try(test(i, j, k)) match { 
    case Success(lines) => lines.toString
    case _ => "Failed"
  }
  q
})

# First Example
val df2 = df.withColumn("D", myUdf($"a", $"b", $"c")) <-- This fails

# Second Example 
val df3 = df1.withColumn("D", myUdf($"a", $"b", $"c"))
df3.show
  +---+---+---+----------+
  |  a|  b|  c|         D|
  +---+---+---+----------+
  |  1|  1|  3|Success(3)|
  |  1|  2|  3|Success(6)|
  +---+---+---+----------+
```

1) How is it possible to get [0-9] values for the integer case (instead of Success(3) and Success(6) -- i.e. remove the Success and the parenthesis -- 3 and 6 can be characters)?  Also, how do I add success/ failure to each row?

2) Is it possible to use Try match to check when the Udf fails, without doing error handling at each step - How do we go to the next computation when it fails on one?  Note:  There are tons of computations going inside the 'test' method.

3) What are potential alternate methods for globally checking the udf?

Comment: Is `k: Int` in the udf supposed to be String? Also `df` on the last row should probably be df1 and the last two assignments can't be named df1. What do you mean in part 3 (globally checking the udf)?

Comment: @Shaido - It could be an Int here and a String (pass/ fail in another column).  By globally - I mean that I do one try/catch or Try/match and get Pass/Fail in one of the columns (without it crashing) and results for where it Passed in the second column (with null or something for where it failed).  If I know which row it failed on, I can then look at the column values to handle the error.

Comment: Since you return a success as a String in the udf, I would assume it's a String in that case? You can't have both since the udf will not run if the types doesn't match. For the last part, wouldn a simple filter suffice? I.e. filter out the rows that have "Failed" in the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `Try`, however, note that the `Try` should surround the whole body of the `test` method and not only be applied on the result (you also should not use the `return` keyword here). After that use `match` to get the result.

```
def myUdf = udf((i: String, j: Int, k: String) => { 
  def test(ii: String, jj: Int, kk: String): Try[Int] = Try {
    val q = i.toInt * j * k.toInt
    val m = q * i.toInt
    q
  }

  test(i, j, k) match { 
    case Success(lines) => lines.toString
    case _ => "Failed"
  }
})
```

Note that `k` as well as `kk` are of type String since that is what you have in both the test dataframes. If you use `Int` and a column value can't be implicitly converted (such as "df"), that row will not run the udf and you will get a `null`.

Result using the two dataframes:

```
+---+---+---+------+
|  a|  b|  c|     D|
+---+---+---+------+
| as|  1| df|Failed|
|  1|  2|  3|     6|
+---+---+---+------+

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  3|  3|
|  1|  2|  3|  6|
+---+---+---+---+
```

1. As can be see, this will give only the values or `"Failed"` as a result, the Success is removed, i.e. the result is returned as a String.
2. Upon failure in the `test` method, an exception will be raised which is caught by the `Try`. This means that the method will exit upon failure and not continue on to the end.
3. To find all rows which failed, use the `filter` method: `df2.filter($"D" === "Failed")`.

Comment: Really useful! Thank you